# ¿Intento compilar en Ionic y siempre me genera este error? sea con el equipo (móvil) conectado o con Build

Tags: android, ionic, windows

> Total time: 48.275 secs
>   Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>   Unzipping C:\Users\Teo.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9\gradle-3.3-all.zip to C:\Users\Teo.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9
>   Exception in thread "main"
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:219)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:149)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:163)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:215)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
>   Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:219)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:149)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:163)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:215)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android --device (exit code 1).

Answer (score 0):

Trata de volver a compilar el proyecto con `npm install` ya que puede estar corrupta la carpeta de *node_modules*.